# Sublime for Julia setting path of ZMQ

Tags: ide

I wanted to use a fast IDE (Juno slows down the entire computer) for Julia (new programming language not a person), so I found on github this installation guide:

https://github.com/quinnj/Sublime-IJulia

I am using a Bionic Ubuntu and Sublime version 3.1.1

Currently I get the error message when opening Sublime "ZMQ Shared Library not found at /home/gingerale/.julia/v0.3/ZMQ/deps/usr/lib/libzmq.so"

I followed the instructions on the github page but since there was no "julia" or "zmq_shared_libary" variable anywhere in the settings file I added these 2 lines:

"zmq_shared_library": "/home/gingerale/.julia/packages/ZMQ/ABGOx/deps/usr/lib",

"julia": "/home/gingerale/julia-1.0.1/bin",

Still it gives me the same error message, and I dont know where the wrongly asumed path of my ZMQ is even located.